# Backbone.js: Best way to handle multiple nullable filter parameters

Tags: backbone.js

have the following function on my **collection**:

```
getFiltered: function (status, city) {
        return this.filter(function (trainer) {
            return ((status === null) ? trainer : trainer.get("TrainerStatusName") === status) &&
                    ((city === null) ? trainer : trainer.get('City') === city);
        });
    }
```

What is is best way to deal with nullable params passed in i.e. if city it null then ignore filter/fetch all and if status is null then ignore filter/fetch all

The code above works, but curious about alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Ok, first off, I'm a little confused by your question; the title says its about handling "nullable" parameters, but your code looks like it is dealing with "special case" parameters (specifically "all") ... except for the case of trainer being null, but I don't think that is even possible when iterating through a Backbone collection.</strike>

*** * Edit * ***
OP updated the question, so the above is no longer relevant.  I've also updated my answer accordingly.

In any case, there's nothing at all wrong or unusual about your code; ternary operators are a standard way of handling one-off special cases.  If you're looking for alternative ideas though, here's one that uses an extra function to DRY out (eliminate the duplication of) your code:

```
function matchesOrAll(expected, actual) {
    return expected === null || expected === actual;
}

getFiltered: function (status, city) {
    return this.filter(function (trainer) {
        return matchesOrAll(status, trainer.get("TrainerStatusName") &&
               matchesOrAll(city, trainer.get("City"));
}
```

*** * Edit * ***

Now that we're talking about null and not "all", it's worth pointing out that there is a better pattern for simpler cases of nulls/undefined.  If you were just filtering cities, for instance, the code could just be:

```
getFiltered: function (expectedCity) {
    return this.filter(function (currentCity) {
        return expectedCity === (currentCity || expectedCity);
}
```

In other words, you could take advantage of Javascript's "truthiness", and the fact that disjunctive (ie. `||`) booleans expressions return the first truthy value.  This eliminates the need for a ternary, and many libraries use this pattern to fill in un-provided arguments; for instance, here's a line from jQuery that sets the "target" argument to a new object if none is provided:

```
target = arguments[1] || {};
```

Unfortunately though, when you're dealing with properties/attributes of things (eg. `trainer.get('foo')`) instead of just objects directly (eg. `trainer`), there's no good shortcut you can use (other than making a function).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually updated that code after I posted the question. Modified it now to fit the question.